# Funnel Chart in plotly

Tags: python-3.x, plotly

I am trying to create a funnel chart using plotly and am not having any luck. Even the canned examples from plotly don't work for me, can someone please help?

```
from plotly import graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Funnel(
    y = ["Website visit", "Downloads", "Potential customers", "Requested price", "invoice sent"],
    x = [39, 27.4, 20.6, 11, 2]))

fig.show()
```

I get this huge traceback error:

lueError: 
    Invalid value of type 'plotly.graph_objs.Funnel' received for the 'data' property of 
        Received value: Funnel({
    'x': [39, 27.4, 20.6, 11, 2],
    'y': [Website visit, Downloads, Potential customers, Requested price, invoice
          sent]
})

```
The 'data' property is a tuple of trace instances
that may be specified as:
  - A list or tuple of trace instances
    (e.g. [Scatter(...), Bar(...)])
  - A list or tuple of dicts of string/value properties where:
    - The 'type' property specifies the trace type
        One of: ['area', 'bar', 'barpolar', 'box',
                 'candlestick', 'carpet', 'choropleth', 'cone',
                 'contour', 'contourcarpet', 'funnel',
                 'funnelarea', 'heatmap', 'heatmapgl',
                 'histogram', 'histogram2d',
                 'histogram2dcontour', 'isosurface', 'mesh3d',
                 'ohlc', 'parcats', 'parcoords', 'pie',
                 'pointcloud', 'sankey', 'scatter',
                 'scatter3d', 'scattercarpet', 'scattergeo',
                 'scattergl', 'scattermapbox', 'scatterpolar',
                 'scatterpolargl', 'scatterternary', 'splom',
                 'streamtube', 'sunburst', 'surface', 'table',
                 'violin', 'volume', 'waterfall']

    - All remaining properties are passed to the constructor of
      the specified trace type

    (e.g. [{'type': 'scatter', ...}, {'type': 'bar, ...}])
```

Comment: Are you running the latest version of Plotly, which is 4.0.0?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you’re using version 3, in which case you will need to use `go.Figure(data=[go.Funnel(...)])` (basically wrap your funnel trace in an array... only in version 4 is this optional)